# Vispy: How to draw only one quarter of a plane

Tags: python, vispy

I want to show only 1 quarter of a plane, is there any method to do that? I've tried all options of `visuals.Plane()` but not successfully. I also tried to change value of `vertices['color']` and the result is same. Here is my code:

```
import vispy
from vispy import geometry
from vispy.scene import visuals, widgets
from vispy.scene.cameras import TurntableCamera
from vispy.scene import SceneCanvas

class Vis():
    def __init__(self):  
        self.canvas = SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', title='vispy', show=True, size=(1280, 720))
        self.canvas.events.key_press.connect(self._key_press)
        self.grid = self.canvas.central_widget.add_grid()
        self.view = widgets.ViewBox(parent=self.canvas.scene,
                                camera=TurntableCamera(distance=10.0))
        self.grid.add_widget(self.view)
        visuals.XYZAxis(parent=self.view.scene)
        vertices, faces, outline = geometry.create_plane(width=2,
                                                        height=2,
                                                        direction='+z', width_segments=1, height_segments=1)
        self.floor = visuals.Plane(width=2,
                                 height=2,
                                 width_segments=1, height_segments=1,
                                 vertex_colors=vertices['color'], edge_color='k', direction='+z',
                                 parent=self.view.scene)

    def run(self):
        self.canvas.app.run()

    def _key_press(self, event):
        if event.key == 'Q':
            self.destroy()

    def destroy(self):
        self.canvas.close()
        vispy.app.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    vis = Vis()
    vis.run()
```

Comment: If you want to draw 1/4th of a plane, why not just change the coordinates of the plane to 1/4th of itself?

Comment: Could you describe your use case? Why do you want to view only a quarter of the plane you're creating? You could try changing the coordinates as suggested by @RobinDeSchepper or you could add a camera (view.camera = 'panzoom') and "move" the camera to a position so it only sees 1/4th of the plane.

Comment: yes, changing the coordinate by adding (delta_x, delta_y, de;ta_z) is solution.  Thanks

Comment: By the way, do you have any solution to draw cube at any position using vispy. The API provided by vispy just draw tube at (0, 0, 0) and there is no option for pos. I dont want to draw it by many lines